# Create new object with the same name of the union type

Tags: f#

I want create an instance of Person. Person is a type of Animal. When I try to create a Person, the IDE says me "This expression was expected to have type 'Person', but here has type 'Animal'".

```
type Person(name) =
    member this.Name: string = name

type Animal =
| Person of Person
| Cat
| Dog

let person: Person = Person(name = "John")
```

Comment: I'm not sure why it's like this so I won't add it as an answer, but if you add `new` it works: `let person: Person = new Person(name = "John")`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I don't want use the 'new' keyword and if I use 'new', the IDE says me 'new' is redundant.

Comment: Interesting. I only tested it in F# Interactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Person` refers to both the type and the case of the Discriminated union.

You can invert the definitions so it will resolve to the last one:

```
type Animal =
    | Person of Person
    | Cat
    | Dog
and
    Person (name) =
        member this.Name: string = name

let person: Person = Person(name = "John")

// then to create an animal
let animal = Animal.Person (Person(name = "John"))
```

Alternatives solutions are to use `new` keyword as @MarcinJuraszek suggested in the comments or considering a different name for the DU case and the type.

Comment: "Duplicate definition of type, exception or module 'Person'".

Comment: How would you create an `Person` of type `Animal` in this scenario?

Comment: @Matiasd I only post the error which the IDE says. And the union Person has no parameters, but the Person class yes.

Comment: @JohnDoe works on my machine in both fsi and a code file. Which version of VS / F# are you using? I know there was a breaking change regarding the order the definitions are loaded. Anyway the error you're getting suggest something different, like something else you have in your project. Try to run the snipped I posted in fsi. Don't forget to reset the fsi session before.

Comment: @Gustavo I'm testing the source in a single file in VS Code.

Comment: @JohnDoe that's weird. I don't have VS Code, but tried it in Visual Studio for Mac and works as well.

Comment: @JohnDoe Have you checked what version of the compiler is used by VS Code ("FSharp.fsiFilePath")?

Comment: @Matiasd Sorry, I didn't copy the last line of code. I don't understand why I must specify Person is Animal.Person. Your code works.

Answer (score 1):

In F# names acts as bindings to types and values and at any time you can redefine what a name "points" to. E.g.

```
// lets define type A
type A(name) = member this.Name : string = name
let x = A("test")

// lets "bind" the type name 'A' to a new type
type A(number) = member this.Number : int = number
let y = A(10)

printfn "type name of x: %s" (x.GetType().Name) // prints 'type name of x: A'
printfn "type name of y: %s" (y.GetType().Name) // prints 'type name of y: A'
```

So `x` and `y` are both of a type named `A`, but not the same. The same logic applies to `Person` and `Animal.Person`, and dependent on the order you define them in, the last defined will be the one referenced when typing `Person`.

As mentioned, you can use new or definition order to access both. You could also decide to put the `Person` class in a different module than `Animal`.

```
module Inner = 
    type Person(name) ...
```

This way you can access your types by prepending the module name.